# Jsoup for posting a form and getting response

Tags: java, android, asp.net, jsoup

I'm creating an android application for myself so i can easily access my school schedule on my phone, and I am using [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/).

First I'm fetching the input fields of the form i need to submit, and getting some cookies like this:

```
Connection.Response res = Jsoup.connect("domain.com/default.aspx")
    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0")
    .execute();

cookieMap.putAll(res.cookies());
doc = res.parse();

Elements inputs = doc.select("input");
for(Element e : inputs){
    dataMap.put(e.attr("name"), e.attr("value"));
}
```

After this I'm trying to post the form and retrieve the data but i can't seem to get the correct html.
I am trying this and the response html is not the page i want.

```
Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect("domain.com/default.aspx")
    .data(dataMap)
    .cookies(cookieMap)
    .method(Connection.Method.POST)
    .followRedirects(true)
    .ignoreContentType(true)
    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0")
    .execute();

doc = response.parse();
```

I have checked the location with `response.url()` and the url is equal to `domain.com/showtimetable.aspx` which is the page you are redirected to if you submit the form normally in a browser

All help i greatly appreciated

Comment: Did you make sure that `dataMap` and `cookieMap` contain the data you expect?

Comment: Yes, the dataMap and cookieMap seem to contain the correct information.
If i use the data from the maps and post the form via the `Postman - REST Client` extension for Google Chrome it gives me back the correct result

Comment: You say that you found that the url is `domain.com/showtimetable.aspx` but in both cases you use `domain.com/default.aspx`. Are you using the wrong url?

Comment: They should both be using the first url since the form is supposed to redirect me to the second url after posting.

I think i solved it however. A simple spelling mistake on my part (I went over it so many times, i can't believe i missed it...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seems i have solved it by myself.

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29732631/jsoup-submitting-a-post-to-a-form) question right before posting this and thought it was my solution. However when i tried to add code to ignore the search button further up on the page, nothing changed.

I looked over my code once more only to see I misspelled the id of the search button...